# Error returning a float value from excel - PHP

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm doing an import with PHP (Laravel) and when I get to a float column in excel it returns this value = 2.0456135709057 and the value in excel is this = 204.561357090573% is there some kind of conversion to get the right value?

Comment: Excel stores the factor, and applies formatting. If you generate an excel yourself make sure to apply formatting to that cell as well if you want to format it as percentages

Comment: I tried that but it returns the same thing

Comment: 204 % = 204/100 = 2.04, so the value is correct. It's just a matter of setting the format. Please be more specific, which result and/or format you expect.